# Numpy array - change the next element based on a change on previous

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have two numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(5)
b = np.array([1.0, 1.1, 1.05, 1.2, 1.25])
```

I'd like that element `a[1]=a[0]*b[1]`, lets call this `a[1]` a `new_a`, then `a[2]=new_a*b[2]`. Can this be done without using a loop in numpy? With a loop code looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    a[i+1] = a[i]*b[i+1]
print (a)
```

prints:

```
[ 1.      1.1     1.155   1.386   1.7325]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "cumulative product". There is already a [built-in function `cumprod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) for this.

```
>>> numpy.cumprod([1.0, 1.1, 1.05, 1.2, 1.25])
array([ 1.    ,  1.1   ,  1.155 ,  1.386 ,  1.7325])
```

Comment: You did solve my particular problem, but what about a general case where you can't ignore the value of ``a``?

Comment: @enedene: You could do `b[0] *= a[0]` before calling `cumprod` if you could modify `b`, or multiply the whole result by `a[0]` (i.e. `cumprod(...) * a[0]`.